# How to load combobox value to CC field in Outlook VBA?

Tags: vba, outlook, combobox, userform, cc

I have a userform combobox that allows users to select a project email. I want to be able to select this email, and click on a button in the userform which loads the email into the CC field. I've got this code right now, but it's giving me an error. Any help is appreciated.

```vb
Private Sub Attach_Click()

    Set oMsg = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    
    Set objRecip = oMsg.Recipients.Add(Me.cmbPC.column(0))
    objRecip.Type = olCC
    
End Sub
```

Error that pops up:

> The operation failed. The messaging interfaces have returned an unknown error. If the problem persists, restart Outlook. Cannot resolve recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Recipient.Resolve](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipient.resolve) method which attempts to resolve a `Recipient` object against the Address Book.

```
Sub CreateAssignedTask()  
 Dim myItem As Outlook.TaskItem  
 Dim myDelegate As Outlook.Recipient  
 Set MyItem = Application.CreateItem(olTaskItem)  
 MyItem.Assign  
 Set myDelegate = MyItem.Recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev")  

 myDelegate.Resolve  
 If myDelegate.Resolved Then  
    myItem.Subject = "Test task"  
    myItem.Display  
 End If 
 
End Sub
```

You may find the [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/) article helpful.

Comment: Hi Eugene, thanks for the reply. Would the above code be placed into my combobox code or 'ThisOutlookSession'?